# Struts2 Exception Handling

Tags: exception, struts2

> How can I set single error page for every errors occured during
>   Execution in Struts2. My error page is as below.

**error.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>HOME</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2 style="color: red;">Error Occurred during processing your Request...!!!!</h2>
</center>
<hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need global exception configuration. Take a look at [this](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/exception-configuration.html)

Comment: It gives following error **org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "struts" must match "(package|include|bean|constant)*"**

Comment: Where are you getting this exception. It is related to syntax error in xml file like invalid tags or unclosed-tags.